# DatabaseMail stops sending mails

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

Our SQL Server Service was running with service account `NAM\ServiceAccount`. It was member of the Windows server's **administrator** group. We used to get mails regularly.

2 days back, due to some permission/access control activities, the service account `NAM\ServiceAccount` was removed from the Administrator group. Since then, we are not receiving any mails from the SQL Server agent jobs. It seems like the service account has to be part of the administrator group to send mails.

Is the above scenario true/expected? then what are the other workarounds?

Also, I have added the `NAM\ServiceAccount` explicitly to the folder where DatabaseMail.exe resides with full control. `NAM\ServiceAccount` is member of 
**SysAdmin** server role in SQL Server.

I am using SQL Server 2014 Enterprise with Windows server 2012 R2.

Comment: What is the "Log On As" account for the SQL Server Agent service?

Comment: @DMason - SQL Server Agent service is running with the same service account i.e. NAM\ServiceAccount (same a SQL Server Service Account).

Comment: Did the [Mail Profile](https://3.bp.blogspot.com/-EixFaW4N6yI/WEluczgeooI/AAAAAAAAFIY/83EppyIYHaIMm5QAYEZpD-_lV-3AffHpQCLcB/s1600/itsalljustelectrons.blogspot.com%2B-%2BSQL%2BServer%2BAgent%2B-%2BAlert%2BSystem.png) get disabled for the SQL Server Agent Alert System?

Comment: @DMason, It is enabled there. I have not done anything else other than removing the account from the `Administrators` group.

Comment: Anything in the Database Mail log? Anything in the SQL Server Agent error logs? What do you see in `msdb.dbo.sysmail_faileditems` and/or `msdb.dbo.sysmail_allitems`?

Answer (score 0):

To send Database mail, users must be a user in the msdb database and a member of the DatabaseMailUserRole database role in the msdb database. To add msdb users or groups to this role use SQL Server Management Studio or execute the following statement for the user or role that needs to send Database Mail.

Reference
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188719(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: The Service account has SysAdmin acces in SQL Server. I have updated the post.